# Symfony API Configuration

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, yaml, symfony-2.5

I want to create an API to communicate with a REST Web Service.

For this, I'm building this API as a library. I Just create the folder structure:

```
├── composer.json
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── src
    └── PkgRoot
        └── PkgName
            ├── XXXAPIFactory.php
            ├── XXXAPI.php
            ├── XXXAPIRestImpl.php
            ├── XXXResponse.php
            └── Protocol.php
```

Now, I'm trying add a configuration for the `API-KEY`. I believe this should be added in `config.yml`.

Should I change all these structure the be like a `Symfony Bundle`? How can I add and register configurations parameters in `config.ym`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not **mandatory**, but I think that you definitely should. Why aren't you using a Bundle ?

Using a Bundle would permit you, among so many other cool things, [to create a friendly configuration as you want](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html).

Comment: Only bundles accepts configurations parameters? I do not found any architecture guideline for `Symfony2` to explain when use bundle or a simple API.

Comment: No, you could parse the configuration thanks to the Yaml component for example, but why not using the right tools that Symfony2 is providing if you decided to use the framework ? Do you have any reason why you would not use the Bundle system ?

Comment: No. I'm only trying to undestand what is a Bundle and why I should use bundles.

Comment: What is called a "Bundle" is a set of files organized logically and using specific conventions that are defined by the Symfony framework, in order to use the Symfony solution properly. A good example is the one that you just described, with the configuration process. If you look at the link that I gave to you, you should see that ways to parse configuration data are simplified and use Symfony tools. Using Bundles permits you to respect the Symfony Full-stack framework "way" to use its set of tools.